# Google functions endpoint HTTP 500 error using vertex ai

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, artificial-intelligence, vertex

I'm in a course and can't resolve the issue with the given tutorial. Unfortunately it's so incomplete for a beginner like me, it's easy to get lost. I'm following the from: https://codelabs.developers.google.com/moviescore-prediction-vertexai#0

My guess is the problem in the step 6 but I'm also not sure if I use the appropriate url either. Although I've managed to train the vertex model and successfully deployed it, but somehow I can't connect it together with the java file, I get an error referencing at line 48.

Because the tutorial doesn't show any contextual help, which parameters should I use, first I've tried connect it with the parameters I've filled in the vertex deployment steps but I always get an Http 500 error.

I hope somebody could give me a a help or a step by step detailed guide especially on the step 6 and how do I reach the endpoint properly.